# Access PostGIS from R on Windows XP

Tags: r, windows-xp, postgis

Is there any easy way how to access PostGis data in R on Windows XP?

I thought I can try `rgdal`, but there is no easy way how to add PG driver (see `file.show(system.file("README.windows", package="rgdal"))`. Therefore this simple piece of code does not work:

```
library(rgdal)
mylayer <-readOGR(dsn="PG:host=localhost user=MyUser dbname=MyDb password=Secret port=5432", layer = "MyLayer", verbose = TRUE)
```

Then I have found [qGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) plugin called [manageR](http://www.ftools.ca/manageR/). Unfortunately, there is a dependency to rpy2 plugin which is not available anymore.

I have no problems using shapefiles, but my intention was to integrate postgis data with current data warehouse and then use R for analytics.

Is there any known simple way how to use PostGIS and R or I have to change OS?

Comment: What type of geometries? Point, polygon, etc?

Comment: @Toews Polygons, I would like to display map of Czech Republic, probably by using spplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been previously dealt with on the r-sig-geo mailing lists.

Searching for 'postgis rgdal windows' on rseek.org finds previous discussions.

In short - not positive, because the windows rgdal is compiled using a minimal set of drivers - because compiling for lots of others - all of which have different versions - would just transpose the problem into one of the wrong version or missing postgis (in this case).

Going via FWtools may be an option.

Comment: Or you could build gdal from source, with the postgis driver, and build rgdal agains that.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thank you Paul, I'm switching to Linux, our whole BI infrastructure is OSS and I'm sure it will be better to work with this software stack using OSS OS :)

Comment: The advantage of Linux is the availability of developer tools like compilers, building gdal from source is not too hard.